# How can I code a link that when clicked opens a web page within the GUI in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a set of links displayed in Qlabels in pyqt5. Now, I would like to make them clickable, and when done so, they open webpages within GUI. So far, I have found examples where when a link is clicked, it opens web pages externally, e.g. in a standard browser.

Comment: Use [`QWebEngineView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) from the QtWebEngineWidgets module. See [this tutorial](https://zetcode.com/pyqt/qwebengineview/).